# readonly attribute toggle

Tags: jquery, readonly

i have a input type

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" readonly="true" />
```

i have a checkbox which when will be clicked will cause the textbox to be editable...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="ch" onclick="check()" />
```

how cud i fix it???

i use a script

```
function check()
{
if(document.getElementById('ch').checked=true)
     document.getElementById('ch').readonly=false;

}
```

Comment: why is this question tagged jQuery? Are you using jQuery?

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Answer (score 5):

This is a shorter alternative (assuming you add the proper ids to your controls):

```
$("#ch").change(function() {
    $("#name").prop("readonly", !$(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function check() {
   document.getElementById('name').readOnly = 
                   !document.getElementById('ch').checked;
}
```